# Setting border to overflown image in CSS

Tags: css

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/7zhLm/5/

The image inside is larger than the div supports.

Therefore it is cropping the rest (`overflow-x: hidden`).

I am trying to create a white border around the image, but it doesn't seem to work.

After checking what's going on there with dev tool I saw that the lower part overlays the white border.

How to I fix that?

Comment: Do you want to compress the image [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/7zhLm/7/)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`. You can just use `overflow:hidden;` as it works on any browser while `-x` and `-y` are not supported by older ones.

Anyway, to avoid it you can add another `<div>`. Check the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/yDSBY/), and here is the updated code:

```
<div id="fixed_event_1" class="splashTabLogout" >
<div>
<img src="http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/demo/Sample%202.jpg" width="300" />
</div>
</div>

.splashTabLogout {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    /* border-radius and box-shadow stuff */
}
.splashTabLogout > div {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zhLm/6/)
You tried to set a border with a padding. Change it to a 10px white border.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you have is fine. It's semantic, simple -- don't change it. Change the details about it, and fix the CSS, and you'll be rockin': http://jsfiddle.net/7zhLm/9/

CSS

```
.splashTabLogout {
    border: white solid 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.22) 0 2px 6px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.splashTabLogout img { width:300px }
```

HTML

```
<div id="fixed_event_1" class="splashTabLogout" >
    <img src="your-pic.jpg" />
</div>
```

Note: Including width/height inside an `img` tag is valid. Period. In a gallery of images, or anywhere else, where you may have multiple images with the same dimensions, it's often easier, and less code to declare the width/height from the CSS file. FYI